# Find the top N most popular elements

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a List of TrackDay objects for a runner going around a track field on different days. Each pair of start/finish times signal a single lap run by the runner. We are guaranteed that there is a matching start/finish date (in the order in which they appear in the appropriate lists) :

```
TrackDay() {
    List<DateTime> startTimes
    List<DateTime> finishTimes
}
```

I would like to find the top N days (lets say 3) that runner ran the most. This translates to finding the N longest total start/finish times per TrackDay object. The naive way would be to do the following:

```
for (TrackDay td : listOftrackDays) {
    // loop through each start/finish lists and find out the finish-start time for each pair.
    // Add the delta times (finish-start) up for each pair of start/finish objects.
    // Create a map to store the time for each TrackDay
    // sort the map and get the first N entries
}
```

Is there a better, more clean/efficient way to do the above?

Comment: Use Collection.sort() with a custom Comparator.

Comment: I'd do what Jawad said, and add a `totalTime()` method to the `TrackDay` class

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Thanks for the suggestion. Can you expand a little bit on how exactly such a comparator could work with the assumption that TrackDay cannot be changed in its definition. A code snippet would greatly help

Comment: The only issue with `Collections.sort(...)` is that this will happen in place and if there is meaning to the ordering of his lists, it will subsequently be lost after the sorting operation.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 True, I created a temporary list containing all the totalTimes value and the temporaty list is sorted not the original list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're trying to solve is well-known as [Selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), in particular - [Quick select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). While sorting in general works good, for large collections it would be better to consider this approach, since it will give you linear time instead of N*log(N).

Comment: It seems that the Quick select is for finding the kth largest in a list as opposed to the first k largest in a list.  Could you give an example of how Quick select can be used in this case?

Comment: @JohnBaum the first k largest in a list are simply all those that are equal to or larger than the kth largest element.

Comment: This answer is a good one. The OP has the right idea about creating a map of days & total times. But if you want best performance, you should then use this algorithm instead of Java's sort(). The latter would unnecessarily sort the whole list, instead of just selecting the top N. It's a shame the Java API doesn't have a partial sort function; the C++ Standard Library has.

Comment: So, after finding the kth largest (say 3rd largest if i want to find the top 3), do I just loop the Remaining trackDays to find those larger than the 3rd largest?

Comment: Nope, when you found largest k-th largest (the pivot will point to it) - you will need to iterate from 0 to K (K is the index of pivot) and get all the K largest items. Please note that thay might not appear in the sort order - there's no "merge" - just "partition", hence sorting doesn't really occur.

Comment: If you are doing this a lot maybe a sorted list is better. Once your list is sorted, complexity drops to O(1). So it is exspensive only  the first time . the quick select will always be O(n)...

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be linear time. I have assumed that startTimes and finishTimes support random access. I don't know what API your DateTime is part of, so have used java.time.LocalDateTime.

```
public List<TrackDay> findTop(List<TrackDay> trackDays, int limit) {
    limit = Math.min(limit, trackDays.size());
    List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(limit, Duration.ZERO));
    List<TrackDay> result = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(limit, null));
    int lastIndex = limit - 1;
    for (TrackDay trackDay : trackDays) {
        Duration duration = Duration.ZERO;
        for (int i = 0, n = trackDay.startTimes.size(); i < n; i++) {
            duration = duration.plus(Duration.between(trackDay.startTimes.get(i), trackDay.finishTimes.get(i)));
        }
        Integer destinationIndex = null;
        for (int i = lastIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (durations.get(i).compareTo(duration) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
            destinationIndex = i;
        }
        if (destinationIndex != null) {
            durations.remove(lastIndex);
            result.remove(lastIndex);
            durations.add(destinationIndex, duration);
            result.add(destinationIndex, trackDay);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```